# Execution time with parallel for

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, execution-time

I was curious about the time spent to do a for with a single thread, or with multithreading (using openmp), so I wrote this code to see the difference:

```
#define N 1000000000 // 10^9

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i, *a = malloc(N * sizeof *a);
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        a[i] = i;

    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time Spent: %lf\n", time_spent);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

But then a strange thing happens: with the `#pragma` rule, the execution time was about 4.6s, but without it, it was about 3.6s. How can it be possibile? Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe I'm not using the correct timing function?

Comment: On a non-realtime platform I would not really suspect so little difference. Here a better way would be to see the disassembled code to comprehand the change. Then you can indirectly estimate the performance delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clock()` return value of `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` clock. This clock is described in `clock_gettime(3)`:

```
CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID (since Linux 2.6.12)
          Per-process CPU-time clock (measures CPU time consumed by all
          threads in the process).
```

Use `clock_gettime()` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` in order to get correct measure.